# Oracle complex string replacement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I've got the following table

```
mytable 
type         | id       | name           | formula  
"simple"     | 1        | "COUNT"        | "<1>"  
"simple"     | 2        | "DISTINCT"     | "<2>"  
"simple"     | 3        | "mycol"        | "<3>"  
"complex"    | 4        | null           | "<1>(<2> <3>)"
```

Now I would like to read this table and add an additional column which replaces the formula string.
For id 4 I would need: `"COUNT(DISTINCT mycol)"`
Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: uhh.... _why_ are you doing this?  Note that you won't be able to 'directly' run any query you re-constitute this way; you're going to need a stored procedure at minimum (at which point, it's going to be much simpler to do this inside the SP _anyways_...).  You may have the easiest time by doing this in your application layer.  However, **rarely** is this sort of 'flexibility' needed; what problem do you think you're solving?

Comment: Is this an example of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 11 it may looks like this:

```
select
   type, id, name, formula, value
from 
   mytable
   left join (
      select
         id_complex,
         listagg(decode(pos, 2, name, part)) within group (order by occ, pos) as value
      from 
         (
            select
               id_complex, occ, pos,
               regexp_replace(pair, '^(.*?)(<.*?>)$', '\'||pos) as part
            from
               (
                  select
                     id as id_complex,
                     occ,
                     regexp_substr(formula||'<>', '.*?<.*?>', 1, occ) as pair
                  from
                     (
                        select level as occ from dual
                        connect by level <= (select max(length(formula)) from mytable)
                     ),
                     mytable
                  where type = 'complex'
               ),
               (select level as pos from dual connect by level <= 2)
         )
         left join mytable on part = formula and type = 'simple'
      group by id_complex
   ) on id = id_complex
order by id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0cf4/18)